# WordPress - Get all categories with filtered Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `wp_dropdown_categories` to generate a list of categories as the dropdown options, by setting the `hide_if_empty` to `true` in parameters, the function will only list out categories with attached posts.

But what I want to achieve is I **only want to show categories with active posts**, I have custom fields `from_date` and `to_date` to determine the validity of the posts so I can filter the active posts with the `meta_query` below:

```
array(
  'key'     => 'to_date',
  'value'   => $today_date,
  'compare' => '>='
)
```

Is there a way I can filter down the categories by meta query, as currently the category will be outputted as long as there are posts attached to it.

Trying to look for something like:

```
<?php 
  $args = array(
    'show_option_all' => 'All',
    'hide_empty'      => 1,
    'selected'        => $selected,
    'hide_if_empty'   => true,
    'value_field'     => 'slug',
    'meta_query'      => array(
      // Conditions to filter out categories without active posts
    ),
  ); 
?>

<div id="filter-select-wrapper">
  <?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: As per my knowledge, there is no built in function to do it directly. You can either built a custom SQL query or use `WP_Query` to target all posts with `from_date` and `to_date`, and save categories in an array, and later create a dropdown manually.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code to show posts which are active from today:

```
<?php 
  $today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
  $args = array(
    'show_option_all' => 'All',
    'hide_empty'      => 1,
    'selected'        => $selected,
    'hide_if_empty'   => true,
    'value_field'     => 'slug',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'to_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
  ); 
?>

<div id="filter-select-wrapper">
  <?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: I tried adding the meta_query but it's not working, the custom fields are added on the posts.

Comment: `meta_query` isn't an argument for `wp_dropdown_categories`.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code,

```html
<?php
$args = array (
    'showposts' => '1',
    'category_name' => 'apples',
    'paged' => $paged
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
```

For More Information, [Reference Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Comment: I don't think you got my question, what I'm trying to do is to filter out categories.